# Error while deploying a zip package on lambda with a private custom layer: Code uncompressed size is greater than max allowed size of 272629760

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am currently deploying a zipped package on AWS lambda. I am able to deploy a zip which is of size 80 MB (Uncompressed: 315 MB).

However, as soon as I attach a custom layer with compressed size of 4 MB (Uncompressed: 7 MB), I get the above mentioned error.

After this I tried reducing the deployment package size and I could reduced it to 75 MB. (Uncompressed: 300 MB). Even after that if I try attaching the custom layer of same size, I am getting the same error.

**Full Lambda size Earlier: 80 MB (Uncompressed: 315 MB) - This gets deployed successfully.**

**Full Lambda size with old package & layer: 80 MB (Uncompressed: 315 MB) + 4 MB (Uncompressed: 7 MB) = 84 MB (Uncompressed: 322 MB) - This give the subjected error.**

**Full Lambda size with reduced package & layer: 75 MB (Uncompressed: 300 MB) + 4 MB (Uncompressed: 7 MB) = 79 MB (Uncompressed: 307 MB) - This give the subjected error.**

I am not sure on what is actually happening when I add a custom layer? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I wonder why 80 MB (Uncompressed: 315 MB) deployment success, far over the quota... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html

Comment: @shimo,  Even I am wandering that, but I can share more details if required.

Comment: Could you add a snapshot of the Lambda console page showing the package size?